# How to fix problem with Entity Framework Core v3.1.31 looking for Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode 1.0.0.0

Tags: ef-core-3.1, .net-standard-2.0

We're in the process of converting old .NET 4.7.2 code to .NET 7. In the migration we're creating some .NET Standard 2.0.3 projects and moving the data layer code into one so it can be used by both .NET versions. But to do this we need to use an older version of .NET Standard (2.0.3) and Entity Framework Core v3.1.31.

For all of the other developers on our team this works fine. However for myself, when I run the code I get an exception thrown from the data layer .NET Standard project that it couldn't load `Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode 1.0.0.0`. The weird thing is that the Entity Framework Core version we're using is referencing `Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode 1.1.1`

I can't find any reference to the 1.0.0.0 version of Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: You're probably missing some mapping from 1.0.0.0 to 1.1.1.

Comment: Do you mean like a binding in a web.config or something?  If so, why would I be the only one to have this problem?  I've wiped out my local solution and gotten the same solution from our git repository that everyone else uses.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0`? Because I see that popping many times

Comment: Yes, I have too, but no it's definitely the Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode referenced in the exception.  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture...'